# How to share TableView-output?

Tags: swift, tableview

In an app I'm building, see screenshot, I want to make use of the sharing option. The user can make lists and reorder the rows. I would than like to be able to share the complete TableView but I don't know how to implement the code in the *UIActivityViewController*. How do I get the full TableView output as an *activityItem*?

The code I'm using.

```
@IBAction func shareButton(_ sender: Any) {
    let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [how to get the TableView output here?], applicationActivities: nil)

    self.present(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

[Image: app-screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QabvL.jpg)

I just started in this fantastic Swift-world and are proud what I made by now, but I really need a helping hand on this one! Thanks in advance!

Comment: I imagine the first step would be defining how you want this to work.  What format are you going to use to share it?  CSV, HTML, Excel, a 2% quality JPEG of the screen?

Comment: The best format seems to be ‘HTML’ since I don’t want to attach a file but show the data (just section headers and rowcontent) directly.